# How to merge between those lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to clean my code however I can't merge those result lists, each link is in one list, please any thoughts how to fix it?

Here's the code example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def Download_Image_from_Web(url):
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.findAll('img'):
        image_links = link.get('src')
        if '.jpg' in image_links:
            for i in image_links.split("\\n"):
                links_list = list(i.split())
                print(links_list)

Download_Image_from_Web("https://pixabay.com")
```

Result:

```
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/24/00/16/auto-2255161__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/24/13/28/photographer-2256456__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/08/10/23/surfer-2212948__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/10/08/08/church-window-2217785__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/01/05/54/cow-2193018__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/12/19/06/lighthouse-2225445__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/10/19/46/ice-2219574__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/11/22/49/hand-2223109__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/07/18/23/landscape-2211587__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/02/19/57/horse-2196755__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/06/17/43/water-2208931__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/13/17/27/man-2140606__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/08/22/26/meditation-2214532__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/12/16/56/chocolate-2224998__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/14/16/46/red-fox-2230731__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/06/19/37/sculpture-2209152__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/08/09/59/mushrooms-2212899__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/09/16/46/lamb-2216160__340.jpg']
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/07/21/22/wave-2211925__340.jpg']
```

I want it to be like this:

```
['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/24/00/16/auto-2255161__340.jpg','https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/24/13/28/photographer-2256456__340.jpg','https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/08/10/23/surfer-2212948__340.jpg','https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/10/08/08/church-window-2217785__340.jpg','https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/01/05/54/cow-2193018__340.jpg']
```

and so and forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just need to use the empty list and append to it with the strings of i.split()

```
def Download_Image_from_Web(url):
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    links_list = []
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.findAll('img'):
        image_links = link.get('src')
        if '.jpg' in image_links:
            for i in image_links.split("\\n")
                link_list.append(i.split())
    print(links_list)
```

hope this helps

Comment: also now that i think about it link_list = image_links.split("\\n") should word as well, because splitting returns a list

Comment: yes but it doesn't merge them so your first answer work for me

Comment: oh i see sorry about that